# mocha tests time out on Saucelabs

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, saucelabs

I'm just learning to use mocha and Saucelabs so I'm likely making a noob mistake here.

My tests run fine in my browser. They also run fine in a manual session at Saucelabs. But when I run them using the REST interface they time out. Looking at the screen capture I can see that the tests all succeeded. Sauce just didn't notice.

I sent the command to the REST interface like this:

curl https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/gbthr/js-tests \
-X POST \
-u gbthr:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "platforms": [ ["Linux", "googlechrome", ""]],
    "url": "http://gbserver3.cs.unc.edu/theme/tests/testStore.html",
    "framework": "mocha"}'

with those 0000's replaced by my id.

Is there some additional step I have to do in my test to notify saucelabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer here: https://github.com/axemclion/grunt-saucelabs

On test end you add the results to window.mochaResults.

```
var runner = mocha.run();

var failedTests = [];
runner.on('end', function(){
  window.mochaResults = runner.stats;
  window.mochaResults.reports = failedTests;
});

runner.on('fail', logFailure);

function logFailure(test, err){

  var flattenTitles = function(test){
    var titles = [];
    while (test.parent.title){
      titles.push(test.parent.title);
      test = test.parent;
    }
    return titles.reverse();
  };

  failedTests.push({name: test.title, result: false, message: err.message, stack: err.stack, titles: flattenTitles(test) });
};
```